# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit with mysql and mongodb in grails-2.2.2

Tags: mysql, mongodb, grails

I am using Grails 2.2.2 with MySql. For a couple of my domains, I decided to go polygot with out db and introduced Mongo into the mix. This change went to production without any issues and was functional for over 12 hours.

But suddenly then we started getting this exception in our logs:

```
caused by org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC commit failed
com.sonyliv.common.VideoService.getRequestIp(VideoService.groovy:1301)
com.sonyliv.portal.ApplicationFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure5.doCall(ApplicationFilters.groovy:14)
…in.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter (PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
 grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter (AbstractFilter.java:63)
                 com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter (CorsFilter.java:69)
….javakaffee.web.msm.RequestTrackingContextValve.invoke (RequestTrackingContextValve.java:99)
  de.javakaffee.web.msm.RequestTrackingHostValve.invoke (RequestTrackingHostValve.java:151)
      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                                   java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:724)

caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.
                  com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance (Util.java:411)
                        com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance (Util.java:386)
             com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException (SQLError.java:1014)
             com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException (SQLError.java:988)
             com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException (SQLError.java:974)
             com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException (SQLError.java:919)
                   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit (ConnectionImpl.java:1700)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit (DelegatingConnection.java:334)
…cp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit (PoolingDataSource.java:211)
com.sonyliv.common.VideoService.getRequestIp(VideoService.groovy:1301)
com.sonyliv.portal.ApplicationFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure5.doCall(ApplicationFilters.groovy:14)
…in.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter (PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
 grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter (AbstractFilter.java:63)
                 com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter (CorsFilter.java:69)
….javakaffee.web.msm.RequestTrackingContextValve.invoke (RequestTrackingContextValve.java:99)
  de.javakaffee.web.msm.RequestTrackingHostValve.invoke (RequestTrackingHostValve.java:151)
      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

                                       java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:724)
```

However, we were still able to log into mysql from our production server using our DataSource settings. I tried restarting the application, but that didn't help either. Finally, I had to revert back to a pre-mongo version to get things working again.

Has anyone got any clues on why this might have happened? Is there a known issue with Grails 2.2.2 + Mysql + mongo. I have been trying to find out, but still have not got anything concrete. Versions of various techs:

Mongo - 2.4.8

Grails Mongo Plugin - 1.3.3

Mysql - 5.5.33

Tomcat 7

Grails - 2.2.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you posted question about the same thing twice. Why don't you update your first question?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that your `VideoService` class doesn't have `static transactional = false` declared, which means every method called will obtain and hold a database transaction whether it makes any database calls or not. If you have any memory leaks or performance issues which get worse linearly with time, eventually those methods will begin holding the database open beyond the connection timeout, and you get results like this.